# TeaVM: use generated JavaScript in manually-written JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, scala

I've defined aliases for my entry points in TeaVM generated code:

```
<classAliases>
    <item>
        <className>my.InputData</className>
        <alias>InputData</alias>
    </item>
</classAliases>
```

It refers to this dummy code:

```
case class InputData(name: String, value: String)
```

In the generated code, I actually find the alias:

```
var InputData=TC;
```

However, I cannot find out how to use it.

I tried:

```
var data = new InputData("test", "Hello!");
```

but it builds an empty object.

How should I use them?